# How to Bind Multiple TextField Property into One Button

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

```
 btnAddToCart.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.and(
                    fieldQuantity.textProperty().isEqualTo(""),
                    fieldBarcodeID.textProperty().isEqualTo("")));
```

I have this kind of code above and It works really well, but the problem is this It returns me an OR Logical Operator meaning If fieldQuantity isn't empty the button is will be enable. I want it to be like an AND Logical Operator. Where those two field must have to contain before the button will be enabled. Hopes I clarify things here. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code disables the button if both text fields are empty. You want to disable the button if *either* text field is empty: i.e. you need an `or`, not an `and`:

```
btnAddToCart.disableProperty().bind(
        Bindings.or(
                fieldQuantity.textProperty().isEmpty(),
                fieldBarcodeID.textProperty().isEmpty()));
```

Note also I used the [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#isEmpty--) method, which is marginally cleaner, imho.

Comment: Thanks mate it work, but It's kind of confusing,As far as i know using AND operator should return both true condition. and OR returns either of them to execute the statement. in my case i want the two textfield to have contain in order to make it enable.

Comment: @i4mB4rney02 Not sure why it is confusing. In your original code, you use an `and`, which is true if both conditions are true. So your original code disables the button *only* when *both* text fields are empty.  You want to disable the text field if either text field is empty - so you want to disable it if the first text field is empty *or* the second text field is empty.

Comment: It happens reverse, in your given code. Those two textfield must have a value in order to enable the button otherwise it wouldn't be enable. Its kinda confuse cause you use an OR but gives you an AND value.

Comment: @i4mB4rney02 How on earth do you interpret as giving an "AND" value? The logic is "If `fieldQuantity` is empty OR `fieldBarcodeID` is empty, disable the button". It sounds like you don't really understand what OR and AND mean...